# Problem with detecting fullscreenchange in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fullscreen

I'm trying to catch *fullscreenchange* event when iframe comes to fullscreen, but have some problems in Safari.

When I request fullscreen from main document and after that from iframe I never get second *fullscreenchange* event in Safari, otherwise in Chrome all looks good.

Here is some peace of code that illustrate my problem

```
var idoc = frame.contentDocument ? frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;
idoc.open();
idoc.write('<html><body><h1>Hello from iframe!</h1></body></html>');
idoc.close();

function fullscreen() {
    document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

function iframefs() {
    idoc.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}

function log() {
    console.log('document webkitFullscreenElement', document.webkitFullscreenElement);
    console.log('iframe webkitFullscreenElement', idoc.webkitFullscreenElement);
}

document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', () => {
        console.group("document");
    log();
    console.groupEnd();
})

idoc.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', () => {
        console.group("iframe");
    log();
    console.groupEnd();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7bywqzn/

After clicking on "full screen" and "iframe full screen" buttons I have 

On Chrome: [https://snipboard.io/djsigG.jpg](https://snipboard.io/BEaKki.jpg)

On Safari: [https://snipboard.io/oC4SqB.jpg](https://snipboard.io/BEaKki.jpg)

Only after click on "log" in Safari, we can see that *iframe webkitFullscreenElemen* is not *null*: https://snipboard.io/BEaKki.jpg

Does anyone know why it happens and maybe there is some hacks for Safari?

Comment: Please include a [mre] in your question per the site rules. Links are inadequate. Misleading links are especially problematic.

Comment: @TylerH question updated

Comment: If you would like to share a CodePen link, please feel free to do so. But don't include a URL that is named a CodePen URL but points to another URL--that's misleading.